# Combining Color and Image using php/html/javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am creating a section for my website which gives the user the ability to create custom images. They can choose the color of the background and an image from an already provided set of images to put on that background color. Then they will be able to write some text.

[Here](http://www.someecards.com/usercards/create) is a good example of what It resembles to.

The pictures are small at the bottom and when you click them, they land on the background color *(transparent background)*

I was wondering is this job doable with html/php? If yes, Can someone drop few key words I need to search for to be able to learn how to do this?

If not, does javascript do this? Again some keywords to be able to search for it and learn how to do it.

Comment: Try looking into the GD library of functions specifically `imagecreatetruecolor`, `imagecolorallocate`, `imagecopy`.  But you have to start with a transparent image in the front ( foreground), then create a new image of the same width and height as the transparent one but with the color you want as the background, then copy the transparent image on top of the 'background' image.  Then you'll probably have to save it with `imagejpeg` or `image*`  where the `*` is the type of image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi something like this using GD ( note not tested ) and its not the easiest thing to do.

```
$org_image = 'file.png'; //transparent png foreground image.

$Image = imagecreatefrompng( $org_image );
//preserve foreground transparency
imagealphablending($Image, true); // setting alpha blending on
imagesavealpha($Image, true); // save alphablending setting (important);

$height = imagesy($Image);
$width = imagesx($Image);

//create background
$newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$red = imagecolorallocate($newImage, 255, 0, 0);
imagefill( $newImage, 0, 0, $red );

//merge
imagecopy ( $newImage, $Image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height );

//save
imagepng('output.png', $dest, 10);
```